# Rewriting directory name to php script name - but allow ending slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Yes, I have read other similar questions on SO about this, which is how I came up with this possible solution:

```
# Turn on the mod_rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# IF the request filename with .php extension is a file which exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

# AND the request is not for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$

# Redirect to the php script with the requested filename
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

This works by rewriting a request for, for example: `/about-us` to `about-us.php` but it *doesn't* work if you go to `/about-us/`.

I tried the below but it didn't work:

```
# Redirect to the php script with the requested filename
RewriteRule (.*)/? $1\.php [L]
```

Does it have anything to do with the second `RewriteCond`?

Basically I am wanting it to fail (if possible) if the request is for a real file OR directory, but if neither exist than it should rewrite to a PHP script whether the request has an ending slash or not.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rule this way:

When .htaccess and .php files are in a sub directory then use:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/work/Client_Name/public_html/$1\.php -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

When .htaccess and .php files are directly in root of site then use:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$1\.php -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: It might be because I am working out of a subdirectory on my dev machine though?

Comment: Hmmm the updated rule worked *without* the ending slash, but not with it.

Comment: It's 3 directories off the root directory in a dir called `public_html`. Can we set the `RewriteBase` perhaps?

Comment: Yes that's why I wanted to know your sub-dir path relative from `public_html`

Comment: That would be `../../../` to the '''web root''' from `public_html`. But the directory `public_html` serves as the root for this particular site. The files then would be at `/public_html/about-us.php` and requested via `public_html/about-us/`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73094/discussion-between-anubhava-and-brett).